# Configuration file '' can not be found

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-connect

I'm using mysql-server 5.5 and had created a server instance. After created I try to open the instance editor and select `Options File` in `CONFIGURATION` but it says

> Configuration file '' can not be found. New file will be created on
>   apply of changes

and then

> Configuration file did not contain section [], so a new one was added.
>   If that is not correct, please fix the section name in the Server
>   Instance Editor and reopen the administrator.

But I have checked and see that I have a `my.cnf` at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

This cause the problem I can't connect to my database from Eclipse.

So the question is how can I solve this on mysql-server or is there a way to set configuration file for server instance?

P/s: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

**UPDATE**

[MySQL Workbench 5.2.38](http://postimg.org/image/lwakd8l7j/) and [Manage Connection](http://postimg.org/image/jg8qze34v/)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming MySQL Workbench, define the path to your MySQL configuration file for your MySQL connection. To do this:

1. Open Workbench to the Home page
2. Right-click on the appropriate MySQL connection tile, choose "Edit Connection"
3. Choose the "System Profile" tab
4. Set "Configuration File" which for you should be /etc/mysql/my.cnf
5. For good measure, click "Test Connection"

Now, opening that MySQL connection will use the newly configured "Configuration File".

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I couldn't see what you are mentioned about. I'm not sure we are talking about same version of MySQL Workbench. Please see my update.

Comment: Solved it for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my setting from Custom to MacOSx (MySql Package) under:

`Database`>`Manage Connections`>`MySql Connections`>Select `DB Connection`>`System Profile`>`Installation Type`>`(default setting) MySql Package`

Comment: This is the answer. I'm not sure how this issue exists within this software.