# Location of MySQL configuration file (ie: my.cnf) not specified

Tags: mysql

Location of MySQL configuration file (ie: my.cnf) not specified[image]

How can I fixed this thing?
I been trying to reinstall mysqlserver 5.5 / 5.7 and workbench countless of time. But I still not able to fix this issue.

Comment: How about specifying the location of the my.cnf file? Simply follow the link [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-instance-options-file.html) and read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html).

Comment: Read it before. Don't really understood it.

Comment: @RobIII very sorry about it. Anyway I fixed it thanks.

Comment: I am having the same question. MySQLWorkbench says the location is not specified, but it does not tell me where and how to specify the location to MySQLWorkbench. The online documentation does not give this information either. Unfortunately, the questioner says he fixed it, but does not provide any info about how he did so.

Comment: Any Idea for this problem ? No one fixed it yet ? I got the same problem here. @RobIII : Forget about the rules, we really need help , you know ? Just answer it. If the question is  a really poor question, then just edit the question make it better. I'm not sure you are willing to help here.  Well I think you only  just spamming comment for reputation :p

Comment: That solution worked fine for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/31330398/4445238

Comment: @not2savvy Sorry about it. I can't remember how I fixed it. When I recall I will let you know about it.

Comment: @TeddAngTeckLoon Never mind, I have solved it in the meantime and put my findings in below answer.

Answer (score 52):

I solved this problem. Step one: click here

[image]

Step two: and then click here to choose your path

[image]

Step three: my path is `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini`

Comment: what if it is empty? What do I do now?

Comment: Awesome - the whole point:  by clicking Server and then Options File from the menu as pointed out by RobIII is what gave the Error message - it can't find it - so how to set it and THIS answers that question!! Great thx for paying attention and providing screen shots.. I solved my issue quickly. I want to give you 10 upvotes.

Comment: I was able to do this by changing the Installation Type: to one of the other options besides the default Custom

Comment: Thanks Christopher Bell. You pointed out the problem: this file doesn't yet exist. The program says 'could not find', when it should say 'file not created', then prompt for a path. It's an odd miss in what seems to be an otherwise well-designed and solid program.

Comment: This DOES NOT address the issue. This only works for LOCAL MySql installations. If it's running locally, you probably already have root access to change privileges or adjust server configs. A working solution must be done from the client side only to compensate for MySql Workbench not exposing the no-tablespaces option.

Comment: Any ideas if this field is grayed out?

Answer (score 24):

If you already know where your configuration file is located, but just don't know how to specify it in mySQLWorkbench, you can skip steps 1-3 and just follow step 4 in these instructions.

Step 1: Make sure which mysql is running (just in case you have multiple installations on your system) and how:

```
$ ps aux | grep mysql
```

may result in something like:

```
_mysql            120   0,0  3,4  5122736 565108   ??  Ss   Fr01pm   61:05.93 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=_mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid
```

If, in this output, you see that mysqld has been started with the `--defaults-file` option, that option specifies the configuration file used by msql. If so, you have found the configuration file and can skip to step 4.

If not, check if this returns the same binary location as above command:

```
$ which mysqld
```

If not, then make sure you use the full path for mysqld from the first output in the following step.

Step 2: Ask mySQL which configuration files it is using:

```
$ mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"
```

should output something like:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

Step 3: Check the given locations in that order. The first finding should be your mySQL configuration file.

Step 4: In mySQLWorkbench go to *Database > Manage Connections*, then select the connection, select tab *System Profile*, and enter the path and file name in *Configuration File*.

This should be it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guide, but I still have a question about the command in Step 1. You say in the output we can see the mysqld start with '--defaults-file', but how do you see that? And if this is the case, where is the my.cnf located then?

Comment: If it is there (which it usually isn't) the path and name of the configuration file is given right after it.

Answer (score 8):

And if still nothing happens, you may have used the installer Package. If you have, then you must select the Installation Type from the drop-down to reflect that before you locate the configuration file.

Here's a screenshot that follows from the above screenshots
[image: here's a screenshot that follows from the above screenshots]

Also, there may not be a config file and you can create one here, then get out of the Options File, go back in and you will see all the options.

Comment: I didn't have the ini file. I extracted it for windows. I don't know root password also. And I'm stuck.

Answer (score 8):

I changed my setting from Custom to MacOSx (MySQL Package) under: Database → Manage Connections → MySQL Connections → Select DB Connection → System Profile → Installation Type → (default setting) MySQL Package.

Change from custom to default setting:

[image]
Reconnect by testing connection:

[image]

Comment: After doing this 10 times and 10 different ways over the years, this is the easiest method. Then just create /etc/my.cnf and restart mysql.

Answer (score 1):

For maria-db users

1. back up the original /etc/mysql/my.cnf
2. copy and rename /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf to /etc/mysql/my.cnf.

This would fix the problem.

Remember to revert changes after finish.

Answer (score 1):

For those with Mac OS Catalina:

I did not have a my.cnf file. I went to /usr/local/mysql/
and created a directory named etc, which I did not have either.
Then, inside that directory, I created the file (my.cnf).

This is the link that helped me [How to fix --secure-file-priv option error](https://sebhastian.com/mysql-fix-secure-file-priv-error/)

Answer (score 0):

for mysql 5.7 users and MAMP: just create /etc/my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

**macOS 13 and MySQL 8 current:**

1. Open MySQL Workbench on your Mac. Connect into your localhost instance of MySQL.
2. Click the little wrench icon next to **INSTANCE** on the left pane above Startup / Shutdown.
3. Select macOS as System Type, macOS as Installation Type, and the rest will default into place. Copy the location it gives you for the `my.cnf` file.
4. Click Close
5. Now click Options File on the left. It will notice that you don't have a file and will show you default values.
6. Click the Apply... in the bottom right corner.
7. It will then ask you for a password of your current logged in user of your Mac to create and save the `my.cnf` file.
8. Now in the Finder use the keyboard combo of Command-Shift-G and copy in your location we copied early (i.e. `/etc/my.cnf`)

Answer (score 0):

As of November 2023, the correct answer is that there is currently no way to fix this issue. As correctly noted in other answers, you need to supply the no-tablespaces option to mysqldump. MySql Workbench does not provide a way to do that.

All of the provided answers require changing server-side settings to return this as the default behavior. This IS NOT an acceptable solution to a client-side problem.

If you are using a local MySql installation, or if you have system level access to your server installation, you may proceed with the accepted answers as workarounds.