# MySQL - Change secure_file_priv from NULL to either path or empty

Tags: mysql, sql, my.cnf

My OS: Mac Big Sur 11.4

MySQL Workbench Version 8.0.28

As I need to import bulk CSV files to MySQL, my goal here is to **NOT** receive NULL when run:

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'secure_file_priv';`

I have tried [this guide](https://sebhastian.com/mysql-fix-secure-file-priv-error/) as it seems recent by:

- Creating my.cnf in text editor
- Inputing in my.cnf:

`[mysqld] secure_file_priv = ""`

- Saving my.cnf in either `/etc/` or `/usr/local/mysql-8.0.28-macos11-x86_64/support-files`
- Restarting MySQL

But I still received NULL in `secure-file-priv`

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Find the configuration file(s) which are loaded really, and edit one of them, or add according option to the service starting command line. Read official Reference Manual, not third-party articles. [Using Option Files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching, I was able to create `my.cnf` with `secure_file_priv` + path , connect Configuration file to my.cnf and import cvs files using LOAD DATA INFILE.

Here's how I did it:

**A. CREATING my.cnf:**

1. Create `my.cnf` file using text editor
2. In my.cnf, input the below and save on folder of choice (ie. Desktop):

`[mysqld] secure_file_priv = "/usr/local/”`

*When save, untick for *If not extension provided, use “.txt”* so your "Kind" of file is Document.

3. Move my.cnf file to `/etc/`

**B. IN MYSQL WORKBENCH:**

1. Tab ADMINISTRATION (top left)
2. Click Manage Server Connections (next to INSTANCES, screenshot can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39822702/location-of-mysql-configuration-file-ie-my-cnf-not-specified))
3. Change Installation Type to: macOS (MySQL Package)
4. Next to Configuration file > Choose `/etc/my.cnf`
5. Test Connection to check. If succeed, Close.
6. Click Options File under INSTANCES to check if still “...not specified” (it shouldnt be)
7. Quit Workbench
8. **RESTART SERVER** by System Preferences > My SQL > Stop Server and then Start Server again
9. Open Workbench to check

`

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'secure_file_priv';

Expected result: 
Variable_Name: secure_file_priv
Value: /usr/local/
```

`

**C. IMPORTING:**

1. Move my csv file to `/usr/local/`
2. Use

`LOAD DATA INFILE '/usr/local/filename.csv' [...]`