# How can I make MySQL to locate my.cnf file?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to use the `LOAD DATA INFILE` query, but it is giving me an error, `Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement`. I didn't have my.cnf file, so I created one and added

```
[mysqld]
secure_file_priv = ""
```

I tried to put it in many locations like, `/etc/my.cnf`, `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, `/usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf, ~/.my.cnf.`, `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/`, but it didn't work. I also tried changing the configuration file path in workbench accordingly, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45292376/14355835.
How can I make MySQL locate my my.cnf file? I'm using macOS Monterey in case it helps.

Comment: `--defaults-file=...` option in daemon starting command line. *I tried to put it in many locations* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I tackle --secure-file-priv in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-tackle-secure-file-priv-in-mysql)

Comment: @michal no, I have tried the solutions from here too